# Assimilated alif (arabxetex)

Tags: arabic, arabxetex

I am trying to achieve:

[image]

However,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade-Regular.ttf}

\begin{document}

\begin{arab}
    humu al-hufseduna
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

gives me:

[image]

(I am trying to get rid of the vowel on alif.)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `arabxetex` as opposed to using `polyglossia` and just entering the Arabic directly in your source?

Comment: @Alan this is incomparably more convenient for me.

Comment: Fair enough. :)  I don't know Arabic, but this is done at the mapping level. Would you consider this a bug (i.e., is the vowel on the alif inappropriate in full voclalization mode), or is this something "extra" that you need to do.

Comment: @Alan (1) I am not sure whether it is not possible, or I am missing something in the manuals. (2) I would not call it a bug; just a missing feature. (3) To my extremely limited knowledge, this is a fairly common occurrence in Arabic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution. Type `humu "A"l-mufsidUna` The quotes suppress the diacritics on the alif.

You can find further information in section 4.1.3 of the [ArabTeX manual](http://baobab.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/arabtex/doc/arabdoc.pdf) which ArabXeTeX relies on.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade-Regular.ttf}

\begin{document}
    \begin{arab}
        humu "A"l-mufsidUna
    \end{arab}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: +1 Yes, this seems like a good answer. Perhaps you can edit your answer to  put the code into the original minimal example and then show the resulting image.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria Thanks. I tried almost all combinations. Missed that one.

Comment: @blackened You're welcome.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you. Is it so ok?

Comment: Yes, perfect.  Thanks! It makes other users see that the example works. And welcome to TeX.se!