# Omitting the wasla sign

Tags: arabic, arabxetex

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade-Regular.ttf}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{arab}
    be-al-ll-_ahi
\end{arab}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I get rid of the "wasla" sign in fullvocalize mode?

On a related matter,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade-Regular.ttf}
\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
    wa-al-yawme  'l-'A_here
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I omit the wasla sign, and, irrespective, add sukun on the "Lam" following the assimilated alif (with wasla)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade-Regular.ttf}
\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
    wa-al-yawme  'l-'a_here
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

brings the sukun but takes away the madda.

Comment: Possibly related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422180/157295

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following may not suit you as it uses `arabluatex`, but here it is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabluatex}

\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
  bi-.Al"-ll_ahi. wa-.Al-yawmi .Al-'A_hiri
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

More on these intricate patterns in the documentation of `arabluatex` on pp. 10 and 21-23.

[image]